# CakePHP - Routing Using 'admin_' Prefix

Tags: php, cakephp, redirect

I am currently using cake's routes config in order to set up admin views, different from that of the non-admin user. I read the routing chapter of the documentation(cake's), and stumbled upon the prefix routing. Which I thought that it is something I need to use, to accomplish what I need. So I started it with setting up the config/core.php as suggested, and uncommented this

```
Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin'));
```

Then, I added a route in the routes.php :

```
Router::connect('/admin', array('controller' => 'donors', 'action' => 'index', 'admin' => true));
```

From what I understood, with the above set, I can define a specific action for the admin, names like : admin_index  or admin_view, etc. .

So my AppController has a component set like this :

```
 public $components = array(
        'DebugKit.Toolbar',
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginRedirect' => array(  
                'controller' => 'donors',
                'action' => 'index'
            ),
            'authError' => 'Access Denied',
            'logoutRedirect' => array(  
                'controller' => 'users',
                'action' => 'login'
            ),
            'authorize' => array('Controller') 
        )
    );
```

So when a non-admin user logs in he should be redirected to 'donors/index', and when the admin logs in I want to redirect him to 'donors/admin_index'.. How can i do this ?

I tried this :

```
public function beforeFilter(){        

        if(isset($this->params['admin'])){
            $this->layout = 'stafflayout';
            $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array(
                'controller'=>'donors',
                'action'=>'index',
                'prefix'=>'admin',
                'admin'=>true
            );
    }
```

And in the process of testing it out, at first glance I though it worked. but the URL does not change like 'donor/admin_index .. and am still being redirected to donors/index or equivalent, simply to  /donors... Why is this not working ?

(seconndary question)Also during the process of testing this out, I changed my the controller and actions of the Auth component LoginRedirect to

> 'controller'=>'posts'

and

> 'action'=>'index'

other then 'donors', 'index', and when I logged in, I still got redirected to donors/index.. were it should have redirected me to 'posts/index'

Anyone can help me on these two issues? Primary questions is more important though!

Comment: Excuse me, Sir. Would you (or any other experienced user kind enough to help) share that fine documentation with the other beginners, like me, please? I thank you in advance.

Comment: there you go.. http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing 
To understand how prefix routing works in cake, go through the doc provided

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the code is fine!

```
Router::connect('/admin', array('controller' => 'donors', 
'action' => 'index', 'admin' => true));
```

the above will render /donors/index page whenever /admin is written in the url.

Now if you want to add prefix like /donors/admin_index then you have to create one more rule such as:

```
    Router::connect('/donors/admin_index', array('controller' => 'donors', 
'action' => 'index', 'admin' => true));
```

and in beforeFilter function

```
if(isset($this->params['admin'])){
            $this->layout = 'stafflayout';
            $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array(
                'controller'=>'donors',
                'action'=>'admin_index',
                'admin'=>true
            );
```

the above code will redirect to /donors/admin_index and routing will render /donors/index page

Comment: thanks for your reply. Then I must have ignorantly misunderstood (assumed) the when setting the admin cofig key to true, i am telling cake to expect the admin_ prefix! my bad!

Comment: well in that case, I am still getting redirected to donors/index when admin logs in! It seems that $this->params['admin'] is not being set somehow, since that block is not being executed.. I am overriding the beforeFilter of AppController in the UsersController, but I am calling parent::beforeFilter, so I think it should execute! any ideas about this?

Comment: check this by applying echo afollowed by die in beforeFilter and see the output

Comment: This isn't how prefix routes work in CakePHP. The Book has [a section that describes how prefixes in the URL connect to controller actions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing). Quoting: _"...accessing the URL `/admin/users/edit/5` would call the method `admin_edit` of our `UsersController` passing `5` as the first parameter. The view file used would be `app/View/Users/admin_edit.ctp`"_