# cakePHP Routing using two controllers

Tags: php, cakephp, routes, url-routing

I have use a cakePHP framework. I have issue with the routing in cakephp.

I have two controller "Admins" and "Users".

I have write some methods for the "Admins" controller in "Users" controller. See below example.

```
class UsersController {
    public function admin_index() {
       my_code
    }
}

class AdminsController {
    My methods
}
```

As per cakephp routing rules if I want to use admin_index method from the admin controller than use below URL :

```
site_url/admin/users/index
```

I want to remove admin keyword from the above URL.

I have search out lots of on google but I have not got any proper solution.

Thanks in advance for helping me.

Comment: Which version you are using?

Comment: I have use 2.X version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

User prefix in your Router connect

```
Router::connect('/:controller/:action/*', array('prefix' => 'admin', 'admin' => true, 'controller' => 'admins'));
```

if you want to add a condition on your parameters like (':action' is 'addUser' : In this example this router effects only when it's action is 'addUser') than use below code

```
Router::connect('/:controller/:action/*', array('prefix' => 'admin', 'admin' => true, 'controller' => 'admins'),
                                          array('action'=>'index|edit'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use admin_index from AdminsController then your url should be `site_url/admin/admins/index`

Also check this this line in you core.php file:

https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.5/app/Config/core.php#L152

If you need to use `site_url/admin/users/index` for the admin_index method inside your AdminsController then I would prefer to disable the routes from core file and write the routes again.

Please read this too [CakePHP - Routing Using 'admin_' Prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21393383/cakephp-routing-using-admin-prefix). Might be helpfull

Comment: I have used above URL which is mentioned in my question and its work perfect. But I want to remove 'admin' keyword from the URL or display any other text in URL which is call URL in my question. like 'site_url/user_list'.

Comment: The url I have in my answer is not mentioned in your question check again